# SQLITE3 Insert Error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

I'm definitely new to SQL but I feel like inserting is pretty simple. I can't figure out the issue

```
def insert(title, name):
    time = datetime.now()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    query = """INSERT INTO test ('{}', '{}', '{}')""".format(title, name, time)
    c.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
```

When I pass the following:

```
insert(1, 2)
```

I get the error:

`OperationalError: near "'1'": syntax error`

All fields are text if that helps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't pass in parameters to queries using string concatenation, `format`, `%`, etc; you're vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead. `c.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?,?)", (title, name, time))`

Answer (score 4):

You have not properly formatted your insert statement.

Right now you're specifying column names in the parens.  To specify values, you need to use the `VALUES` keyword.  You don't have to specify column names if your providing values for all columns, but you do need to include `VALUES`.

Do not use string concatenation to build queries.  Instead, use parameterized queries, which allows the database driver to escape any user input that could otherwise lead to an injection attack.

```
query = 'INSERT INTO test (title, name, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'
c.execute(query, (title, name, time))
```